# How to Upload Image to server using webservice in Android?

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I have develop android app in which one UserProfile is there. I have send all details of user to server using Ksoap2. I also want to send image to server. But, i don't know how to send image to webservice using Ksoap2 in android.

I have take image from sdcard and convert it to ByteArray. Is there I have to send that parameter as ByteArray of image to webservice? I want to pass all details of user and image to webservice. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the your image into base64 string,and then handle them again to image at server side.

Answer (score 0):

I tried following tutorial, you can also try it, [android upload image to server](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/09/android/android-upload-image-to-server/)
.

Answer (score 0):

You can send it as a Multipart file in a network call using retrofit 2 library. Kindly check this answer as a reference for detailed code snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68511884/8391757

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the your image into base64 string,and then handle them again to image at server side. but it getting a poor quality of image

Comment: Please check your English and explain the cause of the poor quality.