# How to upload an image to server in Android SDK

Tags: android, image-uploading, image-upload

I am working with Android Application. I am new to android development. In my application I like to upload the capture image to Server I am not having any idea in it. I have refer several link but I am not getting any idea. Please some body suggest me how to upload image using post method in Android SDK

Answer (score 1):

You can use normal http technique to upload file to server in java using urlconnection  class.

[How to upload binary file using URLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480160/how-to-upload-binary-file-using-urlconnection)

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("title", new StringBody("yourfile", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), file);
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(myFile);
entity.addPart("file", fileBody);
httppost.setEntity(entity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using retrofit 2 library to make the network call, you can send the image to the server using multipart
First : create a method like the following in your interface

```
@Multipart
@POST("upload")
Call<ApiResponse> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part image);
```

Second : In your Activity where you get the picture use the following code before you call the uploadImage() method

```
File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
    RequestBody requestBody =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), imageFile);
    MultipartBody.Part formData =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", imageFile.getName(), requestBody);
```

Third : call the uploadImage() method and pass the formData as the parameter

See this tutorial as a reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zpBhk3NG3Y&t=6s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHvuSSwlTw4